# Date difference with joda time

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I downloaded joda library and extract joda time to calculate time difference,
Here is my class that calculate date difference: (I'm using `Java 1.7`)

```
public class TimeDiffereneceTest {

static String secondDate,firstDate, dateDifference;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    firstDate = "2014/07/20";
    secondDate = getTodayDate();     // Generate 2014/07/23

    DateDifference(firstDate, secondDate);

}

public static String getTodayDate() {
    Calendar todayDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/MM/dd");
    String strDate = simpleFormat.format(todayDate.getTime());
    return strDate;
}

public static void DateDifference(String firstDate,String nowDate) {
    Date d1=null;
    Date d2=null;

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/MM/dd");

    try{
        d1 = format.parse(firstDate);
        d1 = format.parse(nowDate);

        DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(d1);
        DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(d2);

        System.out.println("Day difference is: "+Days.daysBetween(dt1, dt2).getDays()); // 206!

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

The result should be `3` because today date is `2014/07/23` and first date was `"2014/07/20"` , But has wrong result (`206`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some problems with code :
1) new SimpleDateFormat should throw illegal argument becouse of "YYYY" should be"yyyy" (at least for me this works
2) In DateDifference (should be name dateDifference since its a method, not class - naming convenction)
 You got

```
d1 = format.parse(firstDate);
d1 = format.parse(nowDate);
```

Instead of

```
d1 = simpleFormat.parse(firstDate);
d2 = simpleFormat.parse(nowDate);
```

Try using this code, it works for me.

```
public class TimeDiffereneceTest {

static String secondDate,firstDate, dateDifference;
static SimpleDateFormat simpleFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");


public static void main(String[] args) {
    firstDate = "2014/07/20";
    secondDate = getTodayDate();     // Generate 2014/07/23

    DateDifference(firstDate, secondDate);

}

public static String getTodayDate() {
    Calendar todayDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    String strDate = simpleFormat.format(todayDate.getTime());
    return strDate;
}

public static void DateDifference(String firstDate,String nowDate) {
    Date d1=null;
    Date d2=null;


    try{
        d1 = simpleFormat.parse(firstDate);
        d2 = simpleFormat.parse(nowDate);

        DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(d1);
        DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(d2);

        System.out.println("Day difference is: "+Days.daysBetween(dt1, dt2).getDays()); // 206!

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: and he should use `DateTimeFormatter` to parse the date instead of going through the old Java Date API.

Answer (score 0):

Which java version are you using?

In 7, capital `Y` has a different meaning from `y`. In 6 `Y` is not specified so it throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'Y'
```

Comment: I don't have a 1.7 at hand, but try formatting the parsed date again with "new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");" to see what that outputs. From your question I deduce that you actually need "y", not "Y".

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two issues that I can see (apart from the random unused statics).

1. Y is not the format code for year, y is.
2. d2 is null, you are parsing both strings into d1.

The following code gives me 4 when run today, '2014/07/24'.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
String firstDate = "2014/07/20";
String secondDate = format.format(new Date());

int days = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(format.parse(firstDate)), new DateTime(format.parse(secondDate))).getDays();
System.out.println(days);
```